# Timeout a PHP function after 5 seconds

Tags: php, post, timer

I am making an API call to a service and need to timeout the call after 5 seconds and consider it a "fail" then proceed with the code. If it times out I want to save this to a $timeoutResult variable and then pass that all the way back to the javascript (I can do this part).

I'm just not sure how to do a timed function in PHP. I've seen the documentation on `set_time_limit(5)` but I'm not sure how to do it?

For example:

`$response = $api_calls->apiCall($endpoint, $data);` If this takes >5 seconds I want it to quit/consider the call a "fail" and then proceed onto my error handling further down the code.

I'm not sure how to stop the execution of THIS function by considering it a fail and proceeding.

Would something like this work?

```
set_time_limit(5);
$response = $api_calls->apiCall($endpoint, $data);
set_time_limit(0);
```

This way I set a timeout (which begins when this function inside a function is being called), it tries to execute, and if it finishes it then sets the time out back to infinity?

My cURL settings in apiCall() has a standard timeout of 10 seconds, but for this one particular call I need it to timeout after 5 seconds and then display an error if it times out.

Comment: `set_timeout` isn't what you want here - that will make your entire script time out in that time. You will need to find a way to change the curl config on demand for that call. If you don't control that code directly, maybe you can fork/subclass it and use that one instead.

Comment: Are you looking for the `max time it takes to complete` or `the max time it takes to connect` when referring to the timeout?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy -- I believe it should be the max time it takes to connect. If it takes >5 to connect or the connection is outright refused I need to handle it a specific way.

Comment: @samlev -- that's sort of what I was figuring. I didn't think it would work in this application but couldn't find another way. I guess I'll have to figure out a way to make the cURL accept a timeout case.

Comment: Is this a web application that is accessed through a web browser? If so then I recommend using AJAX and telling AJAX to timeout after 5 seconds. If this is a scheduled task then I fail to see why you want a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not shown the code which actually makes the api call!

While its possible to to set a watchdog timer (SIGALRM) this is only an option on a POSIX system and only when running in the CLI sapi.

You mention that the code uses curl. This has lots of options for controlling timeouts - _CONNECTTIMEOUT[_MS], _LOW_SPED_LIMIT, _LOW_SPEED_TIME and _TIMEOUT[_MS] all [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) in the manual.

Comment: I ended up using a timeout on CURL to get this to work. I needed to add an extra param to my apiCall to accept additional curlopts since 98% of my api calls do not use anything besides the base apicall.

I also intentionally did not post the code for the apiCall().

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional parameter to my `apiCall()` function which accepts an array.

I then looped through this array using

```
if(isset($extra_curl_options) && $extra_curl_options.length > 0){
    foreach($extra_curl_options AS $k => $v) {
        $http_request->setOption(constant($k), $v);
    }
}
```

This will allow me to pass in multiple curl options to the apiCall for the future.